# Sub list items don't format properly

Tags: bug, design

The sub list items just stick together too close. That looks really crappy and makes it hard to read. The purpose of a list is to make it easier to recognize. :)

Example:

For example: The product is 'fruit'

- `product1`: apple;

  - `subproduct1`: red apple;

    - `sub_subproduct1`: small red apple;
  - `subproduct2`: green apple,
- `product2`: banana;
- unicorns

Comment: Almost 4 years after this question and I still see not so good looking lists. The top margin of each nested list is too small. I've just posted a question that contains nested lists in it: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/221708/how-to-add-a-regular-page-under-a-custom-post-type